# Accept input parameter using function in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this script that executes, but I need it to take a user input instead of the setting the variable for `@lastName`.

```
CREATE FUNCTION displayCount() RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @number INT, @lastName VARCHAR(40);
    SET @lastName = 'Ferrier';

    SELECT @number = COUNT(*) FROM Person.Person 
    WHERE LastName = @lastName;
    RETURN @number;
END   
GO

SELECT dbo.displayCount() AS howMany
```

I tried to mess with what I thought would work, but doesn't. I am getting and error

> 'Procedure or function dbo.diplayCount has too many arguments'

I'm sure it's something simple and with me being SO NEW, I can't see it. Thanks for the help!!

```
CREATE FUNCTION displayCount(@lastName VARCHAR(40)) RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @number INT;   
    SELECT @number = COUNT(*) FROM Person.Person 
    WHERE LastName = @lastName;
    RETURN @number;
END   
GO

SELECT dbo.displayCount('Ferrier') as howMany
```

Comment: are you using `SQL Server Management Studio`?

Comment: yes I am using SQL Server Management

Answer (score 1):

Your function looks so good, But I guess you need to use `ALTER` instead of `CREATE` because the function already exists in the DB.

you need to modify rather than create.

```
ALTER FUNCTION displayCount(@lastName VARCHAR(40)) RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @number INT;   
    SELECT @number = COUNT(*) FROM Person.Person 
    WHERE LastName = @lastName;
    RETURN @number;
END  

GO

SELECT dbo.displayCount('Ferrier') as howMany
```

Comment: Sorry that was just a typo when typing the question

Comment: Yeah, I realized that at the same time. I hate being new, but it's a learning experience.

Answer (score 0):

In `SSMS`, expand [your database] > Programmability Folder > Functions folder > Table-valued Functions > Right click > New Inline Table-valued Function....

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      
-- Create date: 
-- Description: 
-- =============================================
CREATE FUNCTION displayCount
(   
    @lastName   varchar(40)
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS howMany
    FROM Person.Person 
    WHERE LastName = @lastName
)
GO
```

Then call it by

`SELECT howMany FROM dbo.displayCount('Ferrier')`

Comment: Why have you chosen to change from the OP's scalar function to table-valued function? Either one can accept parameters.

Comment: Thanks HABO, more like a hindsight on my part of not knowing the use of scalar functions. I've learned something new.